# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [12925, 517]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, regression

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

X9=dataset.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]].values
y9=dataset.iloc[:,29].values
#X9=pd.DataFrame(data=X9)
#y9=pd.DataFrame(data=y9)

X9 = X9.astype('float32')
y9 = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y9.astype('str'))

#X9 = np.array(X9).reshape(12925,1)
#y9 = np.reshape(517,1)

X9 = X9.reshape((12925, 1))
y9 = y9.reshape((517, 1))

linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X9,y9)

linreg.intercept_

linreg.coef_
```

I am a beginner in python. I get the below error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-0f2045f4e5e6> in <module>()
     16 y9 = y9.reshape((517, 1))
     17 
---> 18 linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X9,y9)
     19 
     20 linreg.intercept_

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    332         raise ValueError(
    333             "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
--> 334             % [int(l) for l in lengths]
    335         )
    336 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [12925, 517]
```

my X9.shape is: (12925, 1)
y9.shape is: (517, 1)

could you please guide me to solve this error. im trying to do The MR
parameters were optimized using a least squares algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You are having **12925 lines in your X9** and only **517 lines in your y9**. They should be the same number because for every sample in `X9` you would need a sample in your `y9` to calculate the linear regression.

I don't have your data so I can't really reproduce and provide a proper solution.

First guess would be to recheck the shape of your dataset.

Another guess would be that you have to adjust your reshape:

```
X9 = X9.reshape((12925, 1))
y9 = y9.reshape((12925, 1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice. I try above adjustment. it got the error                                                                     
      ```ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 517 into shape (12925,1)```.    error in **line 18**       @Fabian

Comment: Did you check your dataset. Sounds like there are not enough samples in your `y9=dataset.iloc[:,29].values`.
Another thing might be your label encoder...maybe there are alot of empty classes that are not properly encoded?